# On the conclusion of Riesz's Representation Theorem from Real and Complex Analysis written by Rudin.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

**Theorem.** Suppose $1\le p < \infty$, $\mu$ is a $\sigma$- finite positive measure on $X$, and $\Phi$ is a bounded linear functional on $L^p(\mu)$. Then there is a unique $g\in L^q(\mu)$, where $q$ is the exponent conjugate to $p$, such that $$\Phi (f)=\int_X fg\;d\mu\quad\forall f\in L^p(\mu).\tag1$$ Moreover, if $\Phi$ and $g$ are related as in $(1)$, we have $$\lVert \Phi \rVert = \lVert g \rVert_q.$$

**Proof.** The uniqueness of $g$ is clear.

For any measurable set $E\subseteq X$, define $$\lambda(E)=\Phi(\chi_E).$$ It is easily shown that $\lambda$ is a measure.

Claim: $\lambda$ it is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$.

For $E\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $0=\mu(E)=\int_X \chi_E\;d\mu$ we have that $\chi_E=0$ a.e. in $X$ and then results $\lVert \chi_E \rVert_p=0$. From which we have $$|\lambda (E) |=|\Phi(\chi_E)|\le \lVert \Phi\rVert\cdot \lVert\chi_E \rVert_p=0$$ and therefore $\lambda(E)=0.$ Then from Radon Nikodym Theorem applied to $\lambda$ exists $g\in L^1(\mu)$ such that $$\Phi(\chi_E)=\lambda(E)=\int_E g\;d\mu=\int_X g\chi_E\; d\mu$$ for all $E\in\mathcal{A}$. by linearity of $\Phi$ for all measureble simple function $s\in\mathcal{S}(X,\mathcal{A})$, results that $$\Phi(s)=\int_X sg\;d\mu.$$

Now, we know that for all $f\in L^\infty(\mu)$ exists $\{s_n\}\subseteq \mathcal{S}(X,\mathcal{A})$ such that $|s_n|\le |f|$ and $s_n\to f$ in $L^\infty$. Then from the Dominated Convergence Theorem we have that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Phi(s_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X s_n g\;d\mu=\int_X (\lim_{n\to \infty}s_n)g\;d\mu=\int_X fg\;d\mu.\tag2$$

We were able to apply the theorem as $|s_ng|\le \lVert s_n \rVert_\infty |g|\le\lVert f \rVert_\infty|g|\in L^1$.

$\color{blue}{\text{Moreover, since $\mu(X)<\infty$, results that $f\in L^p(\mu)$ and $\lVert s_n-f\rVert_p\to 0$,}}$

$\color{blue}{\text{then $|\Phi(s_n)-\Phi(f)|\le\lVert\Phi\rVert \lVert s_n - f\rVert_p\to 0$}}$ and therefore $$\Phi(f)\color{blue}{=}\lim\Phi(s_n).$$

Therefore from $(2)$ we have that $$\boxed{\Phi(f)=\int_{X}fg\;d\mu\quad\text{for all}\quad f\in L^\infty(\mu)}.$$

Suppose we have proved that $g\in L^q(\mu)$.

Then we have that both sides of the boxed expression are bounded linear functionals on $L^p(\mu)$. Since $L^\infty(\mu)$ is dense in $L^p(\mu)$, remember that $\mu$ is finite, we have that both sides of expression in box coincide on all $L^p(\mu)$. This is how it ends in Rudin's text Real and complex Analysis.

> **Note.** The conclusion of the theorem is not clear to me.

***I try to make the conclusion of the theorem explicit***

Since $L^\infty$ is dense in $L^p$ we have that for all $f\in L^p$ exists $\{f_n\}\subseteq L^\infty$ such that $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$. Therefore $$\Phi(f)\color{blue}{=}\lim_{n\to\infty} \Phi(f_n)=\lim\int_X f_ng\;d\mu\color{red}{=}\int_X fg\;d\mu.$$

The red equality came from Holder Inequality: $$\lVert f_ng-fg\rVert_1=\lVert g(f_n-f)\rVert_1\le\lVert g \rVert _q\lVert f_n-f\rVert_p\to 0,$$ therefore $f_ng\to fg$ in $L^1$. Where the blu equality came from the blu observation. Right?

> **Question 2.** Is this way of proceeding okay, or is it enough to say that since the two functionals coincide on $L^\infty$ they coincide on all $L^p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boxed part only show that $\Phi (f)=\int fgd\mu$ when $f \in L^{\infty}$. We have to extend this to all $f$ in $L^{p}$. Since $\|s_n-f\|_p \to 0$ and $\Phi$ is continuous we get $\Phi (f)=\lim \Phi (s_n)=\lim \int s_n g$.  The rest of the job is to prove that $g \in L^{q}$ and then conlude, using Holder's Inequality, that $\int s_n g \to \int fgd\mu$ so that we get $\Phi (f)=\int fgd\mu$ when $f \in L^{p}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand why those observations were also made on density. How can we conclude using exactly the things given so far by the proof?

Comment: Functions in $L^{p}$ can be approximated by functions in $L^{\infty}$ in the norm of $L^{p}$ if $\mu (X) <\infty$. [In general $L^{\infty}$ functions do not even belong to $L^{p}$] The existence of $(s_n)$ in $L^{\infty}$ requires $\mu (X) <\infty$. @NatMath

Comment: But, the blue part where is it used?

Comment: That is what I wrote in my answer.  You have to find $L^{\infty}$ functions $s_n$ converging to $f$ in $L^{p}$ norm  and that is what the blue part is about. @NatMath

Comment: Where it is used: Since $L^\infty(\mu)$ is dense in $L^p(\mu)$, remember that $\mu$ is finite, we have that both sides of expression in box coincide on all $L^p(\mu)$?

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand.

Comment: To extend  to the whole $L^p$, isn't it enough that the two functionals coincide on $L^\infty$, which is dense in $L^p$? What I don't understand is why that observation in blue is made.

Comment: @NatMath It is not yet known that the right hand side is a  continuous linear functional since it is not yet known that $g \in L^{q}$. If two  continuous linear functionals coincide on  a dense set then they coincide everywhere but we to don't have continuity yet.

Comment: Thanks, but under the remark in blue I wrote that it is shown that $g\in L^q$. So suppose we have proved this. Is what I did in my attempt okay or is there another way to conclude?

Comment: @NatMath If you know that $g \in L^{q}$ then  your argument is fine. But I suspect that your argument may finally become circular when you try to prove that $g \in L^{q}$. The fact that $\Phi (f)=\int fg d\mu$ for all $f$ may be required to prove that $g \in L^{q}$. Since you have not provided a proof of $g \in L^{q}$ I cannot say anything more about this.

Comment: Sorry, but I edited the post, otherwise we don't understand each other well. I hope I have been clearer now. Thank you.